# What gets called after UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification gets triggered?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, rotation

In my app I'm trying to make my navigation bar not shrink from 44px to 32px when the phone is rotated to horizontal orientation. I've been able to accomplish this by setting the navigationBars frame when the view is rotated and also in viewDidAppear. However, when I push the home button to exit the app and then I reenter the app, the navigation bar still shrinks. So I implemented a notification to detect UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, and in that method I reset the navigationBar frame height to 44px. However, it doesn't work because something is getting called which is resetting my views frame. Does anyone know what gets called after a UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification gets triggered that resets the viewcontrollers frame?

Comment: Is your view constructed from a nib?

Comment: @kocodude - no it's constructed programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

In Your application any class can be an "observer" for different notifications. When you create view controller, you can register it as an observer for the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and specify which method that you want call when that notification gets sent your your application.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

remove observer in ViewWillDisappear/viewDidDisAppear/Dealloc as per your need:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Yes, I did this. After the view gets back from being deactive, it resets it's frame somehow, or reorganizes its layouts, I'm wondering what exactly happens.

Comment: when application became active it posts the notification, and we have added observer to catch that notification and then the task that we defined inside that will work. It is quite simple. You can refer following developer link for some information on notifications-http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes I know. I'm saying, aside from that, when the application becomes active, something else gets called as well that resets the nav bars frame.

Comment: Might be there is some, but i am also not aware of that. Post that here if you got any.

Comment: @CoDEFRo, I am having a similar issue. Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @T.J. - I abandoned the idea of changing the height of the navBar in horizontal mode, but I did fix this problem for disappearing bars (had to make sure I was hiding and showing navigation bar, not just changing it's alpha),

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, if you attach an observer via Key Value Observers you can see that something is called after the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification.